Why does the real time snapshots of user count in GA4 differ from the 'Active Users in the Last 30 Minutes' metric?
We are using Google Analytics 4 (GA4) to track unique users on our Salesforce community sites. The setup is correctly configured, and we can see accurate data for real-time users on the geographical map (e.g., four users logged in, and their locations are correctly displayed).
However, there is a discrepancy in the "Active Users in the Last 30 Minutes" metric. While the real-time geographical map shows the correct number of users, the "Active Users" count for the last 30 minutes differs from this data.
I would appreciate guidance on the following:

How does Google Analytics capture and process data in Reports snapshot for real-time users vs. the "Active Users in the Last 30 Minutes" metric?

What is the methodology behind determining "Active Users in the Last 30 Minutes" and "User data display on geographical map"?

How can we ensure accurate tracking across our community sites?


Additionally, when using GA4's Explore feature, which offers reports like Free Form, User Explorer, and User Lifetime, we are not seeing user IDs or user-related data. Could anyone suggest how we can achieve this through reports, Google Tag Manager, or other approaches?
So far, I have verified that the GA4 configuration is correct, and I expected the "Active Users in the Last 30 Minutes" metric to match the real-time user count.
Steps I followed:

Configured the measurement ID in the Salesforce community site under Builder → Settings → Advanced, ensuring the correct *measurement ID *from the GA4 data stream was used.

Allowed both checkboxes for:



Google Analytics (GA) to access Salesforce data.
IP anonymization.


Relaxed the Content Security Policy (CSP) by selecting the "relaxed CSP" picklist value.

Allowed all trusted site scripts.


Additionally, I’ve explored GA4’s reporting tools, such as Free Form and User Explorer, but I am unable to retrieve user IDs or user-specific data. I’ve also tried adjusting the settings in Google Tag Manager, but this hasn't resolved the issue.
